# How to filter HTML encoded messages in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, html, email-filter

I am using Thunderbird E-mail client v. 2.0.0.23

I would like to filter all HTML encoded messages. For this I created a message filter with a customized header `"Content-Type"` but that does not work as expected (no messages are filtered).

The filter looks like that:

```
"Content-Type" "contains" "text/html"
```

I did not find any related bug or workaround (no add-ons).

Is my filter wrong? Should I try Thunderbird V. 3 beta?

Comment: So this problem was my mistake, the filter is working, but as I am using an imap account, I needed to setup the account for offline use in order to be able to filter on the content-type (or for filtering on Body)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filters on the body of a message to work on an IMAP account, said account needs to be set up for offline use.

In order to do so go to:

> Account settings > Offline & diskspace

and tick "Make the messages in my inbox available when I am working offline"

Then select the ad hoc folders after clicking on "Select folders for offline use ..."

After that my filter will work.

Answer (score 0):

Any emails you receive in HTML format will contain the `Content-type: text/html` specification in the actual body of the message.

So change your filter to the following:

```
Body     contains     Content-type: text/html
```

This will now allow you to filter the emails sent in HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but as I commented above, I forgot to precise that I was using an imap account ... that means no online filtering on Body